# A folder having different sub folders, i want to copy all subfolders from source folder to destination folder

Tags: c#, .net

I have project documents in D:/myprojects/payrole

In these "payrole" i have different files and different sub folders

I need to copy the files and subfolders to  E:/myprojects/payrole

copying files and subfolders from D drive to E drive

**how can i do these process in windows application using c# ?
please give me some idea**

Comment: **Please give us some idea of what you have tried**

Comment: Do you want to copy the files as well or ONLY the folders?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
      CopyFolder(@"C:\Text", @"D:\Sites");

}

    static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string desFolder)
    {
        try
        {
           // files from sourcefolder
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);

    // subfolder from sourcefolder
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);


            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string dest = Path.Combine(desFolder, name);
                File.Copy(file, dest);
            }

            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                string dest = Path.Combine(desFolder, name);

                if (!Directory.Exists(dest))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);

                string[] subfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder);
                foreach (string subfile in subfiles)
                {
                    string subname = Path.GetFileName(subfile);
                    string subdest = Path.Combine(dest, subname);
                    File.Copy(subfile, subdest);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please explain the answer - don't just dump a bunch of code on us.

Comment: The sourceFolder(@"c:\Test") having number of files and folders.        please see the above following code.

Comment: here am getting files and folders from sourceFolder(@"c:\Test") and storing it to instance of string array for files(string[] files)and for folders(string[] folders).

Comment: using foreach to copy all files and folders one by one from sourcefolder(@"c:\Test") and paste in desFolder("D:\Sites").

Comment: note:if desFolder("D:\Sites") not having directory(like folder from sourcefolder(@"c:\Test") ),so create directory using this code (Directory.createDirectory) and paste files same as above.

Comment: I meant for you to explain it in the answer, not in comments!